# What is the average capitalization rate ('cap rate') in the UK?

Tags: reference-request, property, united-kingdom

The capitalization rate ('cap rate') of a property is the net operating income (NOI) divided by the current market price of the property. The NOI is the annual income obtained from renting the property out, minus any costs (maintainence etc.).

I have found a [report](https://mybrand.schroders.com/m/dcb51246b3006214/original/Beyond-Brexit-UK-Real-Estate-Outlook-for-US-Investors.pdf) (which is a few years out of date) which suggest that the average cap rate in London is between 3% and 4%, and that its a bit higher in Manchester.

However, I am interested in estimates of the average cap rate for all types of properties, over the whole of the UK, not just London and Manchester. Any help finding this would be appreciated.

I noticed that most reports cite the [PMA](https://www.pma.co.uk/home/) as providing their information on London, but unfortunately I don't have a subscription, so I can't check whether they cover the rest of the UK.

If this proves hard to find, I would also appreciate 'guestimate' answers, especially for lower bounds on the estimate. For example are the values given for London representative for the rest of the UK? Are they higher? Are there any similar countries whose cap rates we can use as estimates for the UK cap rates?